# How to print a string to logcat for testing?

Tags: android, printing, console, logcat

I know this question has been asked before, but I can't find a clear answer. I'm new to Android Studio and the logcat console confuses me. I have a string date and I want to keep 'track' of it in the console so I know what value it has.

I tried commands like `Log.i` and `console.log`, but they don't seem to work for me.

- Where should I write my print line code?
- Where can I see it when it gets printed?
- Do I have to run the whole app (on the emulator, or on a device) to print the line to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do I write my print line code ?

That is up to you.

> Where can I see it when it gets printed ?

In LogCat:

[image: LogCat in Android Studio]

You will get this from the Android view (usually docked on the bottom edge on the left side). Note that I have sometimes encountered a bug where the automatically-applied filter for your app (right-hand drop-down list, above the output) seems to result in nothing showing up in the output. You may need to remove the filters, then adjust the output based on log level.

You can also view LogCat at the command line via **`adb logcat`** and in the Android Device Monitor (Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor from the Android Studio main menu).

> Do I have to run the hole app (emulator or via a device) to print the line to the console?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks for helping! What is the best way to print a string ? I'm seeing alot of different ways to print stuff.

Comment: @WardPeeters: `Log.d("some tag", "your message")`. Feel free to substitute a different log level as appropriate (`d` is for debug). `console.log()` is a JavaScript thing, for use in Web and hybrid apps, not Java-based Android apps.

Comment: "some tag" would be my string date ? What would "your message" be ? Also when I run the app a bunch of lines come up in the logcat.. am I suppos to find the log.d somewhere ?

Comment: TAG is a filter you can use in the log, Your message would be your date. Log.d("DATESTRING",date); where date is the value you want to print. now filter your log using  DATESTRING to just the log which has that tag name

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show logs in error
you can write

```
 Log.e("Your Tag for identy", "Your String ");
```

if you want to show logs in info
you can write

```
 Log.i("Your Tag for identy", "Your String ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `Log.i` is the correct way to write to Logcat.  [Here is the documentation for Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log).

I typically use a tag that describes the stage I am in (setup, teardown, UI update, etc), and I will usually log any action that can trigger an exception.

To view the Logcat, there should be a window for that in Android Studio.  When the windows is not visible, you can access it from a tab in the lower left corner of the screen: [image: Logcat location in Android Studio]